# Getting database user from a database

Tags: sql

As per requirement i need to get the information **whether an user is present in given database** or not. Whether there is any stored procedure which i can use to get this information of user. I just want to check whether user is present in given database, and proceed further with my usage.

I am using MSSQL Server 2005.

Also i need another information, there is on method **LastErrorMessage()** to get the last error message in ADO. is there any method to get the error number.

Thanks,
Santhosha

Comment: Could you confirm that you mean database user/database login: i.e. the username used to connect to SQL Server?  The alternative is an application user.

Comment: I mean database user. The user which is present in the database.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has logins (server level) and users (database level). Users are permissioned on databases/database objects and are mapped (well not neccessarily) to logins (roles are also at database level).

users are available from the `sys.database_principals` system view in each database

logins are available from the `sys.server_principals`

You need to be aware that you can only see objects/principals which the user you are using to connect to SQL server has permission to see. So a user might exist, even if you don't see it in the views.